# Why does a light beam in a moving light clock follows a V shaped path?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

If I am standing on a platform moving along the X-axis and I throw a basketball vertically upward along the z-axis, the ball also travels along the x-axis. Does the same apply to a photon? According to a special relativity postulate  speed of light is not affected by the velocity of the inertial frame or the velocity of the emitter. If this postulate is true, shouldn't a photon fired vertically as above should travel only along the z-axis but not along the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

We have three events here:

1. photon emitted
2. photon hits the mirror
3. photon comes back to emitter

We know where and when each of these events happened from the point of view of a traveler on a spaceship. He knows that events 1 and 3 happened in the same place, event 3 happened a little bit later than the event 1. Because the emitter is not moving.

From the point of view of the man on Earth events 1 and 3 happened in different places (and, of course, in different moments of time). Let's say coordinates of event 1 is $x_1=0, y_1=0$, coordinate of event 3 is $x_3=a, y_3=0$. Event 2 happened somewhere in between: $x_2 = a/2, y_2=b$. So what was the path of the photon? From event 1 to event 2 to event 3. Photon was not interacting with anything between these events, so it was moving along straight lines. We have a V-shaped path.

It's a simple reasoning and there is nothing relative-theory-specific in it so far. Same reasoning as in a situation with a ball bouncing from the wall on a moving platform.

Difference from classic mechanics is that the speed of photon, traveling along the V shaped path (in the frame of reference of Earth) is the same as speed of the same photon in the frame of reference of the space ship. Both observers claim that the photon has same speed $c$, but they also claim that the distance it traveled between events 1 and 3 is different.

```
If this postulate is true, shouldn't a photon fired vertically 
as above should travel only along the z-axis but not along the x-axis?
```

No. Relativity theory only says that the speed of photon must be the same. Direction can be different.

Answer (score 0):

If I am in a frame where I watch you go by on the platform, the photon certainly does move along both the $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ axes, and as you mentioned it must travel at speed $c$ in both of our frames. At first glance this might seem inconsistent, because the path length of the photon in your frame appears shorter than the one in my frame.

What this ends up requiring is for your clock to run at a different rate than mine, a phenomenon referred to as [*time dilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation). For example, imagine the photon reflecting up and down between two mirrors on your moving platform. If you measure a time $\Delta t$ for it to travel between the mirrors, and (watching as you go by) I measure that it takes a time $\Delta t'$, you can find that these time intervals will be related by:

$$
\Delta t' ~=~ \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
$$

where $v$ is the relative speed between our frames. Note that $\Delta t' \geq \Delta t$ so that I always view your clock as running slower. This is what must occur if we demand the speed of light is the same in all reference frames.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Imagine this. If light doesn't move in the direction along the spacecrafts velocity, it would not keep reflecting since the spacecraft will have moved a little in that time. The light appears to be reflecting vertically for the person in the spacecraft since both the person and the photon have the same velocity component in the direction of the spacecrafts motion. Yes, this is exactly what happens for a ball.

- And yes it is also TRUE that everyone agrees that the *SPEED* (not velocity) of light is exactly 299792458m/s. Why?

Speed is defined as the distance traveled per unit time. Speed= Distance divided by time. So, since the speed of light is the same in all reference frames, the *ratio* of the distance traveled and the time taken must be the same.(Not the distance itself).

So since for a stationary observer, the path of light appears to be travelling in a jigsaw pattern, the distance light travels is longer. To compensate this and to maintain lights invariant speed, time runs faster for the stationary observer compared to the observer in the spacecraft.(Since for the observer in the spacecraft, the light only reflect vertically. Hence a smaller distance divided by a smaller time period.). But in the stationary observers case, since time runs faster, a larger distance divided by a larger time period. Hence the ratio remains the same.

-Time slows down just enough so that the *Ratio* of the distance traveled and time taken remains the same for all observers.

-This is why we equate the speeds.

--To sum it all up, the Ratio of the distance traveled to the time taken must be and is the same for all observers. Not the distance nor the direction.  Since speed= distance/time.  To maintain this time slows down for the observer in the spacecraft.

Answer (score -1):

In reality the basketball was not thrown vertically or horizontally. It was thrown at an angle. The photon also travels at some angle, in a straight line from the sources location at the time it was emitted.

Comment: The ball was not thrown at an angle. What happens is that the ball already had horizontal momentum so, when applied a force in the vertical direction, this leads to the ball having both horizontal and vertical momentum. Photons also have momentum so this applies to them too.

Comment: @Luismi98 No that is incorrect. The basketball is released with an angled trajectory which has only one trajectory (one vector just like any other basketball). Because of gravity it then transitions into a downward trajectory.

Comment: That one vector can be decomposed onto a horizontal and a vertical component. The horizontal component was there before it was thrown up because it was standing on the moving platform. Therefore, the only new component is the vertical one, which appears after a force is applied in the upwards direction.

Comment: @Luismi98 based on what you say, then anything moving has multiple components from every direction in the universe. For example your platform is moving down the road as the earth spins and travels around the sun,  orbiting the galaxy which is moving in some direction. All of this is going on when you throw the basketball in the direction that you call upward. So the basketball ends up having one vector  or thousands of components. Components or not, a basketball or photon can only have one real and physical vector.

Comment: You have just come to the conclusion that space is not absolute. Obviously these horizontal and vertical components are defined relative to the surface of the ground, which we are assuming can be approximated as flat in this scenario.

Comment: @Luismi98 no matter what it’s relative too, any moving object has one real and physical propagating direction.

Comment: We seem to have got stuck in a loop now. Go back to my second comment in the thread to find an answer to that.

Comment: @Luismi98 The OP asked: Shouldn’t the photons fired vertically, only travel along the z-axis and not along the x-axis? That is correct they should only travel vertically along the z-axis if they were fired vertically. My point was they were not fired vertically.

Comment: So you are trying to change the OP's question then? If they were fired vertically, then they were fired vertically. Where do you get the information that they were actually fired at an angle? The OP says it very clearly. Go back to my first comment for the answer to what's actually happening.

Comment: @Luismi98 I am not changing the question. The photons follow a V pattern ONLY because they were never traveling vertically. To be more clear the trajectories there and back were never opposite of each other as in up and down vertically. You cannot disagree with that. In fact you’re very first comment Describe the trajectory as something other than vertical. To answer the original question the light beam follows a V shaped path because the trajectories were NOT vertical.

Comment: One thing is the direction it was fired and a different thing is the direction it travels in. It travels at an angle, even though it was fired vertically. The reason this is possible is because of the source already having horizontal speed.

Comment: @Luismi98 Yes, multiple forces is equal one direction. The photon travels in one direction only and in this case it was an angled direction.

Comment: Ok but you agree then that it was NOT fired at an angle, right?